# Terraform : Invalid dynamic for_each value => Cannot use a set of object value in for_each. An iterable collection is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-loop

In terraform version 1.1.9 am facing the below issue while doing terraform apply.
Help me to fix how this for_each can be done without error.

rke_nodes values sample will be :

```
# Outputs
output "rancher_nodes" {
  value = [
        for instance in flatten([[aws_instance.node_all], [aws_instance.node_master], [aws_instance.node_worker]]): {
    public_ip  = instance.public_ip
    private_ip = instance.private_ip
    hostname   = instance.id
    user       = var.node_username
    roles      = split(",", instance.tags.K8sRoles)
    ssh_key    = file(var.ssh_key_file)
    }
  ]
  sensitive = true
}
```

I have variable.tf :

```
variable "rke_nodes" {
  type = list(object({
    public_ip = string
    private_ip = string
    hostname = string
    roles = list(string)
    user = string
    ssh_key = string
  }))
  description = "Node info to install RKE cluster"
}
```

main.tf :

```
# Provision RKE cluster on provided infrastructure
resource "rke_cluster" "rancher_cluster" {
  cluster_name = var.rke.cluster_name

  dynamic nodes {
    for_each = var.rke_nodes
    content {
      address           = nodes.value.public_ip
      internal_address  = nodes.value.private_ip
      hostname_override = nodes.value.hostname
      user              = nodes.value.user
      role              = nodes.value.roles
      ssh_key           = nodes.value.ssh_key
    }
  }
  upgrade_strategy {
    drain                        = false
    max_unavailable_controlplane = "1"
    max_unavailable_worker       = "10%"
  }

  kubernetes_version = var.rke.kubernetes_version

}
```

I got error when terraform apply :

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
│
│   on .terraform/modules/rke-cluster/main.tf line 6, in resource "rke_cluster" "rancher_cluster":
│    6:     for_each = var.rke_nodes
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.rke_nodes has a sensitive value
│
│ Cannot use a list of object value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.
```

Actual Value when apply it can be list in sometimes:

```
- nodes {
    - address           = "65.2.140.68" -> null
    - hostname_override = "i-0d5bf5f22fb84f5d4" -> null
    - internal_address  = "10.30.8.120" -> null
    - labels            = {} -> null
    - role              = [
        - "controlplane",
        - "etcd",
        - "worker",
      ] -> null
    - ssh_agent_auth    = false -> null
    - ssh_key           = (sensitive value)
    - user              = (sensitive value)
  }
```

Comment: Where is the index value coming from?

Comment: The `for_each` meta-argument accepts a map or a set of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need index. It just should be:

```
  for_each = var.rke_nodes
```

Note: This works only for dynamic blocks. If you use `for_each` in resource blocks, this form of `for_each` (list of maps) will not work.

Comment: I don't think that would work as you can only for_each a map or set of strings but they are providing a list of objects.

Comment: @JakeNelson That's not the case. In dynamic blocks these restrictions do not apply.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to go and do my homework!

Comment: @JakeNelson Yes, I think its a good idea.

Comment: I've removed my answer as yours seems correct and mine wasn't. I've tried to undo my downvote of your answer but it won't let me until your answer is edited for some reason! Sorry about that.
Edit: Fixed my vote. Sorry again, Marcin!

Comment: @JakeNelson No problem. I updated the answer. I think now you will be able to un-downvoate it, if you want.

Comment: Used : for_each = var.rke_nodes 



Getting same error :
Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value
Cannot use a list of object value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.

Comment: @sethuram Please update your code with new version of it, also provide actual value of `rke_nodes` that you are using.

Comment: @sethuram What is the actual value of `var.rke_nodes` that you use?

Comment: @sethuram I mean the **actual** value  `rke_nodes`. Not its definition.

Comment: @sethuram What you provided is not `rke_nodes` as it does not conform to its `type`. Maybe someone else will be able to help you, as I see my comments go nowhere.